# Why my question is downvoted even with all the required info available in the question?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [RDP Client showing different screen (related to SConfig) on VM Startup](https://serverfault.com/questions/1118835/rdp-client-showing-different-screen-related-to-sconfig-on-vm-startup)

I have given all the information such as:

1. Inputs
2. Outputs
3. Error details
4. Valid Question (not seeking for any recommendations or tools or suggestions)
5. Efforts I kept to solve the error before reaching to community

All are in Good Format.
Provided more information based on Commentators ask.

Still, why the question is downvoted and why people are discouraging the new users even full information is available.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to know who downvoted and why, but the general reason for a downvote (seen when hovering over the down arrow) is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

I would guess that the downvoters found the *original* form of the question unclear - maybe the grammar, maybe the links to images that show crucial information.  From reading the comments on the question and answer, it's not entirely clear to me what's going on, so it's likely a couple of other people thought so as well.